# coldfusion Web vs c# Desktop

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, csv, coldfusion

My employer writes intranet applications in coldfusion. I was writing a basic page that fetches sql data and saves it as a csv file, and kept thinking I would have preferred to write it in c# as a desktop application. Now, my company has reasons for using coldfusion, and reasons to continuing to use coldfusion, but I was wondering - I pulled about 50 calculated columns from 2 databases (one was oracle, the other ms sql) and saved the info as a csv file (which the end users open with excel) - Would a windows form have done this faster, or does the coldfusion code run faster (I used no client-side code)

Or, would it have been faster to just do the coldfusion portion as asp?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question as it stands is off topic for SO.  There would be many different reasons why one technology would be better than another in any given situation.  I suggest you build some proofs of concept and make your case for one or the other that way.

Comment: I think I'm being too general. What I really want to know, is there more overhead involved in a web browser than a web browser showing the same information?

Comment: My C.S. teacher's favorite answer was... "It depends".  What kind of overhead are we talking about?  Memory, disk IO, network traffic, processor speed?  Its still a very general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking desktop app vs. web app, web app will win out more times the not. Deploying code to a server that everyone can access vs. prompting users to upgrade a program on their desktop? Web wins out.

Is it faster to run a query and convert it to a CSV in web language A vs. web language B? That's trivial in any modern web language, the overhead is negligible.

If you want to argue for moving from web language A to web language B, then you have to prove the ROI in doing so. What's it going to cost to convert the intranet you have now to a different code base?